# Image of a vector $v$ under Matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let Matrix $A =  \begin{pmatrix}
-4&-3\\
0&-3\\
\end{pmatrix}$. In addition, define the transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ by $T(x) = Ax$

Find the image of $v: \begin{pmatrix}
3\\
3\\
\end{pmatrix}$ under $T$

Now I'm not quite sure what this entails, isn't an image just the span of the linear transformation, so by that, wouldn't it just be the linear combinations that result to $v$?  But instead, the solution is to just apply $T(v)$. Would someone mind explaining this concept of an image to me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question asks for the image of a particular vector, not the image of all of $T$. The image of a particular vector $v$ is simply $T(v)$. The image of all of $T$ would be $\{T(v) : v \in \mathbb R^2\}$. This is a comment instead of an answer because I'm not sure if this answers your concern.

Comment: @Bungo hm, how does this relate to the definition of an image?

Comment: Can you share which definition of an image you are referring to?

Comment: @Bungo "The image of a linear transformation or matrix is the span of the vectors of the linear transformation"

Comment: Right, that's "the image of all of $T$" that I was referring to above, i.e. the image of the linear transformation, not the image of a particular point in the domain of that linear transformation. This question is asking for the latter. The image of $T$ is the set of the images of all of the points in the domain of $T$.

Comment: @Bungo So then shouldn't the image of a particular point in the domain be the span of $T(v)$ rather than just $T(v)$?

Comment: No, if they wanted the span of the image of $v$, they would presumably have asked for it. Probably what is confusing you is that the image of $T$ (i.e. of the whole transformation) represented by the matrix $A$ is the span of the columns of $A$.

Comment: Yeah that's where my confusion comes from, I thought the very definition of an image is the span (in the context of a linear transformation) @Bungo

Comment: "Image of $v$" means where does $T$ send $v$, i.e. $T(v)$. "Image of $T$" means where does $T$ send all of $\mathbb R^2$, which is $\{T(v) : v \in \mathbb R^2\} = \text{span}\{\text{columns of }$A$\}$.

Comment: @Bungo Ohh, thank you! Now it clicks :). Want to add this as an official answer or should I delete the question?

Comment: I'll go ahead and post an answer so we can close this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your confusion comes from the fact that there are two different but related uses of the word "image" in this context.

The image of a single vector $v$ under the linear transformation $T$ is simply the vector $w$ to which $T$ maps $v$, namely $w = T(v)$. Note that the image of $v$ is just the single vector $w$, not the subspace spanned by $w$.

The image of the linear transformation $T$ is the set of the images of all vectors in $\mathbb R^2$, i.e. $\text{image}(T) = \{T(v) : v \in \mathbb R^2\}$.

Note that $\text{image}(T)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$. If $T$ is represented by the matrix $A$, then we can also express the image of $T$ as $\text{image}(T) = \text{span}\{\text{columns of }A\}$.